# MySQL "SELECT .. FOR UPDATE" and "SELECT .. LOCK IN SHARE MODE" examples

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have been looking for some practical examples of MySQL "SELECT .. FOR UPDATE" and "SELECT .. LOCK IN SHARE MODE" queries in transactions. However I couldn't find them and the MySQL docs also uses some difficult understandable examples.

Can someone explain it to me or are there some tutorials with clear examples of when to use it and when not. Do I have to use it before an update or not. It is very unclear for me when to use it and when not.